# Async breaks in template Angular?

Tags: angular

There is a component with template:

```
 <tr *ngIf="(documents | async)?.length == 0">
       <td colspan="8"><div class="nodata">No data</div></td>
 </tr>
```

Where `documents` comes from component:

```
public get documents(): Observable<any> {
   return this.documentsRepository.documents;
}
```

documentsRepository is:

```
  private _documents = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  public readonly documents: Observable<any> = this._documents.asObservable();
```

I fill data using this:

```
this.documentsRepository.setDocuments(response);
```

Why do I get these errors?:

> ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
> at invalidPipeArgumentError (invalid_pipe_argument_error.ts:12)
> at AsyncPipe._selectStrategy (async_pipe.ts:132)
>
> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispose' of null
> at AsyncPipe._dispose (async_pipe.ts:136)
> at AsyncPipe.transform (async_pipe.ts:109)
> at Module.ɵɵpipeBind1 (core.js:25516)

Comment: What does this.documentsRepository.setDocuments look like?

Comment: People from the Stackoverflow community can help you better if you can share the contents of the entire component and template file which is giving problems. A reproducible example on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular-ivy) or a similar website of your choice will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wrap with onInit

```
export class ... implements OnInit {
  ....
  ngOnInit() {
    ...  
    this.documentsRepository.setDocuments(response); 
 }
}
```

Comment: I can not it is callback from request

Comment: @Aurica Can you reproduce just this part with issue in sandbox?  https://codesandbox.io